# What's wrong with my segue code in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to segue into a 'settings' View Controller by clicking a button, and I'm assembling it via code but don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This is my button code:

```
 @IBAction func settingsButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController", sender: self)
    }
```

The View Controller is called 'Settings View Controller' (unsurprisingly). The app crashes whenever I press on it in my Simulator.

It'll probably be a simple thing, but any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't tell us what the crash _is_.

Comment: Make sure that the identifier of the segue is set properly in Interface Builder (must exactly match the literal string)

Comment: Sorry, it's: Thread 1: Exception: "Receiver (<Opna_App.HomePageViewController: 0x7fe0b9e07200>) has no segue with identifier 'Settings View Controller'" - I've tried it both with spaces and without.

Comment: You must set the Identifier of the **segue** not of the controller or something else. Select the segue and press ⌥⌘5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set your `segue identifier` whatever you want (for your question = `SettingsViewController`) from storyboard :

[image]

Hope it helps...